# How can I compare wifi/networking differences between two distros?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, kali-linux

I use Ubuntu as my OS on a Lenovo L440, but am having intermittent issues with the wifi dropping out or failing to connect to a network.

After trying various fixes unsuccessfully I experimented with live booting some other distros to see if any of them would better support my laptop's hardware out of the box, and found that with Kali linux the wifi works perfectly every time.

Kali isn't an appropriate OS to use for my day to day work, so how should I work backwards to compare Kali and Ubuntu and find out which part of the former's networking setup makes my wifi card work?

*Edit:*

- Ubuntu kernel is 4.10.0-38-generic
- Kali kernel is 4.6.0-kali1-amd64

The wireless card is Realtek 8192EE 802.11n, and both distros are using `rtl8192ee` driver, although I'm not sure how to check which version.

*Edit II:*

I have had some improvement by increasing the packet retry threshold on wifi in Ubuntu with `iwconfig wlp2s0 retry 25` (default is 7). That makes me think Kali might be configured with some more aggressive settings in terms of how the wifi tries to connects to the AP.

Comment: What are the versions of the relevant driver on each system? Do they use the same driver? Kernel versions? Have you also checked live booting your Ubuntu? (oddly enough, you do get differences between the live system and the installation).

Comment: @terdon Ok thanks I will look into these. Is there anything else you'd add to the list of factors to check?

Comment: Well, if you report back with these, that would be a good start. I'm no networking expert, those were just off the top of my head.

Comment: "Kali isn't an appropriate OS to use "... probably not, unless you are a unix guru and a forensics expert. May I ask why it seemed, to you, like it should be the alternative to Ubuntu? (which is almost on the complete opposite end of the spectrum, guru-ness wise, as it is user friendly and doesn't necessitate knowledge of inner workings of linux) ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac Kali is the only OS I've found that resolves my wifi issues! Now I'd just like to understand why, so I can switch back to Ubuntu.

Comment: @corintxt Your last comment ("...switch back to...") implies that you have installed Kali and are using it? I am not trying to push you out of your depth but my experience of Kali for 'normal' use (4.13.0-kali1-amd64 + plasma +  the usual packages) is positive. If you have the time and a little patience then, like all things Linux, it can be whatever you choose to make it. My install is a rabid schizoid rottweiler on sedatives. It took a while to learn how to manage it properly, but we get on fine now.

Comment: @corintxt you can gather info : lsmod, and then modinfo yourwifimodule, and then find out if there are any special parameters in your WiFi module or it's configuration that you could use in Ubuntu.

Comment: @bu5hman Thanks, this is useful to hear. If there are any resources on how to configure Kali to be more of a normal desktop OS please let me know!

Comment: @corintxt We are off topic on customising the desktop etc but if you raise a query or go to chat then I will be happy help. WRT the wifi, I have just been experiencing some issues with `networkmanager` after a recent update which appear to be related to how it handles the profiles and permissions. Did you try deleting the relevant profiles in the connection manager gui? Check they are also gone from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` and then try to reconnect?